# How to break down concatenated lists in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and trying to understand how below python code works. Can someone please help me understand the code.
Below is code

```
n=int(input())
marksheet=[[input(),float(input())] for i in range(n)]
i=''
print(marksheet)
print([marks for name,marks in marksheet])
```

my input is

```
2
sam
98
mike
95
```

output i am getting

```
[['sam', 98.0], ['mike', 96.0]]
```

`[98.0, 96.0]`

my second print statement got the result i wanted, but i don't understand what it is doing. I changed  it to something like this and it still worked

```
print([test for yellow,test in marksheet])
```

Can someone please help me understand.

Note: I am very new to python, so I am asking for help. Please don't use any abusive language.

Comment: This is a "list comprehension". Read this section in the python documentation for more info: https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: It also involves "tuple unpacking".

Answer (score 0):

You are unpacking a tuple of name and test_score while iterating in a list.

In the same fashion in order to get the names:

```
print([name for name,marks in marksheet])
```

output:

```
['sam', 'mike']
```

To get the entire tuple list again. Although it is trivial, I am just trying to make you understand

```
print([(name,marks) for name,marks in marksheet])
```

output:

```
[('sam', 98.0), ('mike', 96.0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand your code, it is good to break it down line by line

```
n=int(input()) #takes input from a user and converts it to integer
```

Since input() by default is a string, if you enter a number like 3, the output will be string "3". int("3") converts string 3 to an actual number 3

```
marksheet=[[input(),float(input())] for i in range(n)] # List comprehension
```

List comprehension, in this case, creates a list of lists that looks like this [[int, float], [int, float]], n number of times. So if n from the first line = 2, marksheet will ask to enter 4 numbers.

Ex.:

```
n=int(input()) #let's say enter 2
2
marksheet=[[input(),float(input())] for i in range(n)] #enter 1,2,3,4
1
2
3
4
print(marksheet) #outputs [['1', 2.0], ['3', 4.0]]
```

This one just creates an empty string

```
i=''

print(marksheet) # self explanatory
```

You rather have confusing names here. Since your list looks like [int, float],

```
print([marks for name,marks in marksheet]) # outputs [2.0, 4.0]
```

prints your float. A better print statement is:

```
print([float for int,float in marksheet]) # outputs [2.0, 4.0]
```

Notice that the name doesnt matter. It's just the position of the variables in a list.

```
print([second for first,second in marksheet]) #same thing
```

Hope this helps. Also, my 1 answer :)

Answer (score 0):

**Line 1**

```
n=int(input())
```

This line takes an new line input from console. Here, first line in console is `2` hence, `n=2`

**Line 2**

```
marksheet=[[input(),float(input())] for i in range(n)]
```

It is list comprehension. A more understandable translation would be

```
for i in range(n):
    p = input()
    q = float(input())
    marksheet.append([p,q])
```

**Line 3**

```
i=''
```

Assigning `i` to empty string. Not essential.

**Line 4**

```
print(marksheet)
```

Prints the marksheet list

**Line 5**

```
print([marks for name,marks in marksheet])
```

This can be somewhat confusing. This is list comprehension as well. You are iterating it for each inner array.

```
for name,marks in marksheet: '''Here name would be 1st element of inner array and 2nd element would be 2nd element of inner array.'''
    all_marks.append(marks)
print(all_marks)
```

**Complete working program**

```
n=int(input())
marksheet=[]
for i in range(n):
    p = input()
    q = float(input())
    marksheet.append([p,q])
print(marksheet)
all_marks=[]
for name,marks in marksheet:
    all_marks.append(marks)
print(all_marks)
```